# MongoDB: Check if a field is same in all the documents in that collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How could I check whether a specific field's value if same in all the document in that collection.

I have a collection called `Game` where I store the game responses of the users and in the game, the logic should check whether the responses are all equal or not, so how could I do it ?

Comment: What have you tried to do ? You want to check it at the moment you request the data or after ? This question lacks plenty of information to be answered

Comment: I want to check the moment I request the data

Comment: So you want to query all the data with a specific answer, or you want to make sure all the data have the specific answer ?

Comment: I want to check if the game responses are all the same or not

Comment: show code of what you tried doing and why it doesn't work

Comment: I don't know how to achieve that, if you could give me hint or tell how to check i try to code that out

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the opposite

`find({field : {$ne: expectedValue}})`

If you get a response for this query, then there are documents which is not having the desired value.

Comment: I don't know the exact `expectedValue`

Comment: You can check Steven' answer as it would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count of unique values of that field. If more than 1, they are not the same.

You can also group by the field value.  If more than 1 record, they are not the same.

```js
const rows = await myCollection.aggregate([
 {
  $group: {
    _id: '$theField'
  }
 }
]).toArray()

if (rows.length === 1){
  // same field value
}
```

Or do the counting in the pipeline to save bandwidth.

```js
const rows = await myCollection.aggregate([
 {
  $group: {
    _id: '$theField'
  }
 },
 { $count: 'count' }
]).toArray()

if (rows.length && rows[0].count === 1) {
  // same value
}
```